# css style on jsf page is not rendering correctly on server

Tags: html, css, eclipse, jsf

I am styling my jsf pages but when I run it nothing is displayed on the browser (Chrome).
I am using eclipse kepler ,glassfish4 and primefaces
Here's the html code

```
   <div class="box">
        <p:graphicImage url="images/usericon.png" id="usericon"
            alt="utilisateur IsetN"></p:graphicImage>
        <br></br>
        <p:inputText placeholder="Login" required="true"></p:inputText>
        <br></br>
        <p:password value="#{passwordController.password}"
            promptLabel="#{msg['password.promptLabel']}"
            weakLabel="#{msg['password.weakLabel']}"
            goodLabel="#{msg['password.goodLabel']}"
            strongLabel="#{msg['password.strongLabel']}"    required="true"
            placeholder="Mot de passe" />
        <br></br>
        <p:commandButton value="Connexion" />
        <br></br>
        <h:link url="#">Aide?</h:link><br></br>
        </div>
```

and this is the style

```
     .box{
         height:100px;
          width:100px;
         /*border-radius*/
         -webkit-border-radius:15px;
            -moz-border-radius:15px;
           border-radius:15px;
           background-color:#cdcdcd;
           /*box-shadow*/
           -webkit-box-shadow:0 8px 6px -6px #efefef;
          -moz-box-shadow:0 8px 6px -6px #efefef;
           box-shadow:0 8px 6px -6px #efefef;
           margin:50% 50% 50% 50%;
               }
```

Note: the components without the style works very well.

Comment: *"nothing is displayed on the browser"*  This doesn't seem to be related to CSS in any way. Rightclick the page in browser, do *View Source*. What do you see? Do you see the raw JSF source code, or its generated HTML output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

<h:head>

    <style type="text/css">
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    /*border-radius*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
    /*box-shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #efefef;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #efefef;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #efefef;
    margin: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}
</style>


</h:head>

<h:body>

    <div class="box">
        <p:inputText placeholder="Login" required="true" value="#"></p:inputText>
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

When I ran your CSS, I found that "margin: 50% 50% 50% 50%;" put your grey box in the middle of the screen, but that I had to scroll to see it! I know this is silly, but are you sure that your components aren't just being shown outside of the main scroll region?